# JLabel don't disappear

Tags: java, swing, icons, label

I have a panel in which constructor i create object and imagelabel. It looks like this:

```
zloczyncy.get(0).setX(750);
zloczyncy.get(0).setY(312);
zloczyncy.get(0).Rysuj(zloczyncy.get(0).getX(),zloczyncy.get(0).getY(),zloczyncy.get(0).getImage(),this,2);
```

Rysuj method:

```
void Rysuj(int picturex, int picturey, ImageIcon image, JLayeredPane panel, int w) {
    imagelabel=new JLabel(image);
    imagelabel.setBounds(picturex,picturey, image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight());
    panel.add(imagelabel,w,0);
    panel.repaint();
}
```

Then in other class, in run method i want to remove or just make it disappear, but nothing happens.

```
public void run() {          
    try {
        Mapa panel = new Mapa(frame);
            for(Zloczynca z:zloczyncy){         
                if((this.getX()<=z.getX()+30)&&(this.getX()>=z.getX())){                              
                    if(this.getSzybkosc()>z.getSzybkosc()){              
                        while((z.getZycie()>0)||(this.getZycie()>0)){
                            System.out.println("cios");
                            int ciosB=(this.getInteligencja()*this.getUmiejetnosciWalki())-z.getWytrzymalosc();
                            z.setZycie(z.getZycie() -ciosB);
                            int ciosZ=(z.getInteligencja()*z.getUmiejetnosciWalki())-this.getWytrzymalosc();
                            this.setZycie(this.getZycie() -ciosZ);
                            if(z.getZycie()<=0){
                                System.out.println("dead zloczynca1");
                                z.imagelabel.setIcon(null);
                                panel.repaint();
                                System.out.println("dead zloczynca1/2");
                                break;
                            }
                            if(this.getZycie()<=0){
                                System.out.println("dead bohater");
                                this.imagelabel.setBounds(0,0, image.getIconWidth(), image.getIconHeight()); 
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried `z.imagelabel.setIcon(null); panel.remove(z.imagelabel);`even i tried to change bounds but nothing work, like this label is untouchable or something. When i remove it in panel constructor it works. It doesn't look complicated but i have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: It is horrible to read the code for someone who does not understand your language. I'd recommend you to write everything in English and to COMMENT(!!!) the code you have written so far.

Comment: panel.revalidate();  before panel.repaint();, both are notifiers for LayoutManager to repaint changes in already visible Swing GUI, nothing else from this code, for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Thank you for all answers :D